# Should cover letter etc. be addressed to recruiter?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, canada

I am new in the tech industry and am applying for my first real position. I've noticed there are a lot of recruiters and this is something I'm not very familiar with. It's my understanding that there two types of recruiters: those who work for a recruiting agency and those who are in house and work for the company they recruiter for. What I don't understand is, how is an in house recruiter any different than just a normal hiring manager? Is it because they only bring in candidates but don't actually evaluate them?

This job posting contains an example of my confusion https://www.cybercoders.com/jobs/details/324117/
In what sense is Ms.Lazarus the recruiter if I just found the posting myself? When I write a cover letter I normally start with "Dear Hiring Manager" but if she is the one who's going to be evaluating, should I address it to her? If she's not the one evaluating, then how does she fit in to the hiring process?

I have worked with a few recruiters before and the way things worked with them is they found job openings related to my skill set and they would discuss the position with me and then send the company my resume/cover letter. This is why I'm confused with the linked to posting, if I'm just applying by myself how does recruiter fit in?

Answer (score 3):

Answer: no-one cares. Just send your resume/CV. If they want to hire you they won't care whom you addressed the cover letter to. If they don't want to hire you, it won't help that you addressed the cover letter to the right person.

Answer (score 0):

You should address it to the potential employer either to them directly if you know there name or..

When writing a letter to persons unknown just address the cover letter to "To Whom it may concern" or being realy realy formal "Dear Sirs"

And remember its Yours faithfully or Yours Truly at the end of a latter you don't know the recipient of.

Comment: "Regards" is fine for letter endings, and less overboard than "Yours (blah)"

Comment: @DepressedDaniel regards is more a email thing I have given the formal correct way to address letters in english

Comment: That wasn't what I was trying to ask. I was trying to ask, is the recruiter the one you should address the letter to? For example if Bob's the recruiter, do you address the cover letter to "Dear Bob"?

Comment: @TickTack1 address it  to employer

Comment: @Neuromancer but that's the question, *is* the recruiter the employer?

Comment: @TickTack1 No why would the recruiter be the employer

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and address it to Ms. Lazarus. They put her name and smiling face on the job posting for that very reason.

For most technical positions, your cover letter doesn't have to be too long or involved. Just sell her on your skills, so that she's empowered to sell you to her clients.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, "cover letters" and such do not include postal address information, but I strongly recommend that they should be *customized,* however slightly, for the particular job and company that you are seeking.  No one likes to get "junk mail," and everyone can spot it instantly.