# How address a cover letter to an unknown party

Tags: professionalism, cover-letter

I am about to be applying for a position requiring a cover letter. I did write one for a portfolio when I was in school (high school course with college credits), so I feel fairly comfortable as far as writing one.

However, I cannot remember (or not sure I knew) what to do if I do not know who my intended recipient is. Should it just be written as "To whom it may concern" and that address, or...?

Typically I would start the top of the letter with something like the following:

John Smith

123 X Street

Anytown Anystate 00000

**Follow up:** So, if I didn't know who it was being sent to, but where I was sending it, how would I write the address for a cover letter?

I am in the US, if this changes how it would be addressed.

**Note:** This is being sent online but not via email.

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/how-to-send-a-interview-reminder-to-recruiter/96876#96876

Comment: Have a look at the related questions in the side-bar, this has been covered before. Also, cover letters are usually digital these days and they tend not to use the classic letter format but simply have a salutation without any address lines. If you're applying via email your actual email will often be the cover letter.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks... I did look at a couple related, wasn't sure if I felt they totally applied. I will have a look at them again. Also, I am applying online but not via email if that makes any difference.

Comment: @L.B. [This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5773) is close but only has one useful answer. [This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27941) is more general and the answers seem on point. Check [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5740) as well. There are several other instances ([1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83441), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40826)) of this question being asked and they usually don't get much of a response because related questions have covered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To whom it may concern is a salutation. That wouldn't be part of the address section. If you don't know the person's name, you can put their title or their department followed by the company.

```
Director of Human Resources
Someplace, Inc.
1234 Any St.
Atlanta GA 30010
```

Then, "To whom it may concern" would be appropriate.